# Why aren't HTTP Headers from Oracle Access Manager passing through to WebSphere from IHS?

Tags: apache, oracle11g, http-headers, websphere

I have a IBM HTTP Web Server setup as a reverse proxy for a WebSphere application server. We use Oracle Access Manager for user authentication. There is also a Oracle Webgate running on the IHS server to intercept the requests and check them against the Oracle policy.

I can see the authentication going through and Oracle passes back the value needed in an HTTP Header, OAM_REMOTE_USER. The problem is, at some point in the process, that header is not passed on to the WebSphere Application Server.

The Oracle Webgate is monitoring port 8443, but I am not understanding if that means for the Web Server or the App Server since both are on the same physical machine and have the same server name. If I just create a virtual host on the Web Server for 8443 and do not create the port on the App Server, the headers are going through correctly. The problem with this is that I have to use PreserveProxyHeader for the request to go through the WebGate 8443 port, so after authentication it comes back looking for my Application on port 8443, which does not exist on the Web Server. The only way it can find my application on port 8443 is if I also add a port on the App server for that port, which contains the application.

I guess the main thing I am struggling to understand is if I need to define the port Webgate monitors on the HTTP Server and App Server, or if it should only be on the HTTP Server side. It seems like no matter what I do, at some point the request gets redirected from the HTTP Server to the App Server and strips out any OAM HTTP headers that were there. I've managed to prevent them from dropping by removing the 8443 port from the app server, but now my app cannot be mapped to.

This is WebSphere App Server 8.0 and IBM HTTP Server 8.0.0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the administrative console, click Servers > Server Types > Web servers > web_server_name > Plug-in properties > Request routing. Disable ["Remove special headers"](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/uwsv_plugin_props3.html). Regenerate your plugin configuration XML, and redistribute it.